# Android: Can I get the left/right back gesture areas without calling setDecorFitsSystemWindows

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an android app which requires the user to swipe left/right close to the edge of the screen. The problem I have is that android version 29 interprets this as a back gesture, i.e. the app returns to the previous activity.

These areas are too big to use `setSystemGestureExclusionRects` - they are (much) bigger than the 200dp limit allowed with this function.

I've been able to solve this problem with some code that looks something like,

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { view, windowInsets ->
    val gestureInsets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemGestures())
    view.updatePadding(
        gestureInsets.left,
        0,
        gestureInsets.right,
        0
    )
}
```

That's great and works fine.

However, this approach also turns my layout in to an edge-to-edge layout, but my app isn't well-suited to an edge-to-edge layout, i.e. I don't want my app to have an edge-to-edge layout.

I find that the listener specified in `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` isn't called if `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` isn't called with `false`.

Is there any way for me to find the width of the left/right back gesture area at run-time without having to enable edge-to-edge layout in this way?